# jquery extend vs angular extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, extend

What is the difference between these two extend functions?

```js
  angular.extend(a,b);
  $.extend(a,b);
```

While the jquery.extend is well documented the angular.extend lacks details and the comments there provide no answers. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend).

Does angular.extend also provide deep copy?

Comment: It states, `by copying all of the properties `, and I would assume the use of the word `all` means `everything`, which is synonymous with `deep copy` in the JS world.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I very much doubt it's a *deep* copy. If a property (say, `p`) refers to an object, I'll bet you dollars to doughnuts that after the call, both `src.p` and `dst.p` refer to the *same* object.

Comment: Misleading angular documentation is.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`angular.extend` and `jQuery.extend` are **very** similar. They both do a *shallow* property copy from one or more source objects to a destination object. So for instance:

```
var src = {foo: "bar", baz: {}};
var dst = {};
whatever.extend(dst, src);
console.log(dst.foo);             // "bar"
console.log(dst.baz === src.baz); // "true", it's a shallow copy, both
                                  // point to same object
```

[`angular.copy`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) provides a **deep** copy:

```
var src = {foo: "bar", baz: {}};
var dst = angular.copy(src);
console.log(dst.baz === src.baz); // "false", it's a deep copy, they point
                                  // to different objects.
```

Getting back to `extend`: I only see one significant difference, which is that jQuery's `extend` allows you to specify just one object, in which case `jQuery` itself is the target.

Things in common:

- It's a shallow copy. So if `src` has a property `p` that refers to an object, `dst` will get a property `p` that refers to the *same* object (not a copy of the object).
- They both return the destination object.
- They both support multiple source objects.
- They both do the multiple source objects *in order*, and so the last source object will "win" in case more than one source object has the same property name.

Test page: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/eketan/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/eketan/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Extend!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    (function() {
      "use strict";
      var src1, src2, dst, rv;

      src1 = {
        a: "I'm a in src1",
        b: {name: "I'm the name property in b"},
        c: "I'm c in src1"
      };
      src2 = {
        c: "I'm c in src2"
      };

      // Shallow copy test
      dst = {};
      angular.extend(dst, src1);
      display("angular shallow copy? " + (dst.b === src1.b));
      dst = {};
      jQuery.extend(dst, src1);
      display("jQuery shallow copy? " + (dst.b === src1.b));
      $("<hr>").appendTo(document.body);

      // Return value test
      dst = {};
      rv = angular.extend(dst, src1);
      display("angular returns dst? " + (rv === dst));
      dst = {};
      rv = jQuery.extend(dst, src1);
      display("jQuery returns dst? " + (rv === dst));
      $("<hr>").appendTo(document.body);

      // Multiple source test
      dst = {};
      rv = angular.extend(dst, src1, src2);
      display("angular does multiple in order? " +
                  (dst.c === src2.c));
      dst = {};
      rv = jQuery.extend(dst, src1, src2);
      display("jQuery does multiple in order? " +
                  (dst.c === src2.c));

      function display(msg) {
        $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that jQuery allows you to specify boolean `true` as the first argument in order to make a deep copy. See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN

Comment: One major difference: extend is only copying values if there is a property with the same name, copy is copying the whole object, so you lose databinding if you use it on a $scope variable! Like asafge's answer states it.

Comment: `angular.extend()` won't copy getters and setters for you. See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8573

Comment: @demisx: Neither does jQuery's. They both copy the *value* of the property, which I'd probably argue is correct behavior.

Answer (score 31):

There is one subtle difference between the two which was not mentioned in previous answers.

jQuery's .extend() allows you to conditionally **add key,value pairs, only if the value is defined**. So in jQuery, this: `$.extend({}, {'a': x ? x : undefined});` will return `{}` in case `x` is undefined.

In Angular's .extend() however, this: `angular.extend({}, {'a': x ? x : undefined});` will return `{'a': undefined}`, even if `x` is undefined. So the key will be there, no matter what.

This could be a good or a bad thing, depending on what you need. Anyway this is a difference in **behavior** between the two libraries.

Comment: I've got same problem too. related example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/2ca7AfIhgolmwaNaYvY4?p=preview

Comment: This is definitely a bad thing if you expect both functions  to behave the same. There was even a pull request in 2014 to fix this, which was not implemented: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8387

Answer (score 6):

The 1.0.7 angularjs build states that the extend & copy methods no longer copy over the angularjs internal $$hashKey values.

See release notes @ https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

angular.copy/angular.extend: do not copy $$hashKey in copy/extend functions. (6d0b325f, #1875)

A quick test of the angular.copy in Chomre dev tools method shows that it does do a deep copy.

```
x = {p: 3, y: {x: 5}}
Object {p: 3, y: Object}
x
Object {p: 3, y: Object}
z = angular.copy(x);
Object {p: 3, y: Object}
z
Object {p: 3, y: Object}
x
Object {p: 3, y: Object}
z.y.x = 1000
    1000
x
Object {p: 3, y: Object}
p: 3
y: Object
    x: 5
    __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
z
Object {p: 3, y: Object}
p: 3
y: Object
   x: 1000
   __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

angular.extend on the other hand does a shallow copy.

Comment: *"A quick test of the angular.copy in Chomre dev tools method shows that it does do a deep copy."* No, it doesn't. `extend` doesn't, anyway, I didn't look at `copy`.

Comment: Ah, `copy` does, `extend` doesn't: http://jsbin.com/eketan/2 But the question is about `extend`, not `copy`.

Comment: Yep - you had already answered the extend question pretty thoroughly when I was posting. I wanted to make sure the copy method is also evaluated since it could provide a solution for what they are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for clarifying that matter so thoroughly :)

Answer (score 1):

.extend() in AngularJS works similarly to jQuery's .extend()

http://jsfiddle.net/Troop4Christ/sR3Nj/

```
var o1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: {
        d:3,
        e:4
    }
},
    o2 = {
        b: {
            f:{
                g:5
            }
        }
    };


console.log(angular.extend({}, o1, o2));
console.log(o1);
console.log(o2);
```