# Inject AngularJS object as TypeScript class (methods missing)

Tags: json, angularjs, typescript

The Angular gets some JSON from a service as part of the route resolve.

The JSON is injected into the controller as an Angular-ish deserialized object.

The properties of the object line up with the provided TypeScript class, so `vm.foo.displayName` is successfully displayed on the html page for example.

But I think the methods defined in the TypeScript class are nowhere to be found, so when I try to call `vm.foo.run()`, the console prints the error: **TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'run'**

```
module app.Samples {

    export class Foo {
        public typeName: string;
        public displayName: string;

        public run(): void {
            alert("Running!");
        }
    }
}

module app.Samples {

     interface IFoobarScope {
         foo: Foo;
     }

     class FoobarController implements IFoobarScope {
         foo: Foo;

         static $inject = ['foo'];
         constructor(foo: Foo) {
             var vm = this;
             vm.foo = foo;
             vm.foo.run();
         }
     }

     angular
         .module('app.Samples')
         .controller('app.Samples.FoobarController', FoobarController);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as far as AngularJS is concerned, it's just passing any old object into your controller function. TypeScript provides the syntactical sugar for the `Foo` class within your code, but it's not going to give an object a `run()` method if it doesn't have one.

You could create a copy constructor for your `Foo` type:

```
constructor(foo?: Foo) {
    if(foo) {
        this.typeName = foo.typeName;
        this.displayName = foo.displayName;
    }
}
```

And then do this in your controller:

```
constructor(foo: Foo) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.foo = new Foo(foo);
    vm.foo.run();
}
```

Alternatively, you could skip the copy constructor approach and use `angular.extend()`:

```
constructor(foo: Foo) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.foo = new Foo();
    angular.extend(vm.foo, foo);
    vm.foo.run();
}
```

Comment: That's what I suspected, but something about your solution / the way you said it made a lightbulb go off.  It's not necessary to manually reflect the injected object unto the constructed object.  I'll mark as the answer if you can edit from `vm.foo = new Foo(foo);` to `vm.foo = new Foo(); angular.extend(vm.foo, foo);`  :-)

Comment: Good synopsis of angular.extend and/or angular.copy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797659/jquery-extend-vs-angular-extend

Comment: @RJB There may be some merit in the approach I originally posted, so I've edited my answer to additionally include your suggestion.